# Laurent series and rearrangement of its terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

Consider a Laurent series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$, where $a_n,z,z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$.

*Is it true that $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$ where $b_n=a_{-n}$*?

I know that by definition $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}.$$

However, let's consider the following example:

$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (n+0i)$ diverges, $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-n+0i)$ diverges,

but $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} [(n+0i)+(-n+0i)]=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} 0$ converges.

So, based on the example, I think that in general:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n \neq \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right).$$

But this implies even that $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n} \neq \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right), $$

and this is not true, I guess.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in general they are different, but that's just because the term $a_0$ appears twice in $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$ and only once in $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n$; if $a_0=0$, they are actually equal.

On the other hand, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_n(z-z_0)^n=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$. This follows from the fact that the convergence is absolute in the annulus of convergence.

Comment: Thank you. So if we write $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n=a_0+\left(a_n(z-z_0)^n+\frac{b_n}{(z-z_0)^n}\right)$, what we are doing is just rearranging the series $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n(z-z_0)^n$, and this is possible because of uniform convergence?

Comment: No. Because of *absolute* convergence. Yes, I wrote *uniform* convergence, but that was an error and I have edited it.